# Plugin triggered on deleting reference between Marketing List and Campaign - Plugin Registration Tool

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I am working on plugin that should populate `Number of Campaigns`(Whole number) field on `Account` , `Lead` and `Contact` entities. It should count on how many `Campaigns` are these records used on. Connection is Marketing List. Some record is on `Marketing Lists`, and `Marketing Lists` are used on `Campaign`s and plugin should calculate number of `Campaigns` for particular record.

I have made a plugin, and registered steps that will triggered it on `AddListMember` and `RemoveMember`, messages for `Marketing List`. Plugin is working fine for that messages.

My problem is how to trigger it when a `Marketing List` is removed or added on `Campaign`. I haven't found any message for that.

Is there any message for that event, or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For N:N relations you can use Associate/Disassociate messages. You can find more details [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmshop/archive/2012/05/14/how-to-trigger-a-plugin-for-many-to-many-relationship)